# tinyMCE editor not updating on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, tinymce

I have a HTML form with tinyMCE editor in it the form has an image upload option with a button which on click sends the file to ajax which then posts the value to the controller and uploads the image, I am good till here and everything is working. What I want is once the image has been uploaded it should be appended to the editor which is not happening. My javascript:

```
$('#uploadImageOnTheFly').click(function()
{
var photo = document.getElementById('photo');

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('photo', photo.files[0], photo.value);

var editorvalue = $('#textbody').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin/uploadPhotoForTemplate',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        if(parsed.status === 'success')
        {
            var body = $('#textbody');
            html = '<img src="' +parsed.url +'">';
            body.prepend(html);
        }
    }
});
});
```

My HTML form :

```
<div class="form-wrap">
    <div class="panel panel-body">
        <form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1/admin/infringing/email/templates/show/1" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="vsKR2MtkUxpTI7ku97Hsknz8RurV4ioQeJLkA9NP">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" value="Alibaba edited" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" value="contact@alibaba.com" id="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="subject" type="text" value="Testing" id="subject">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="file" id="photo">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" id="uploadImageOnTheFly" class="btn btn-info">Upload</button>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <textarea style="min-height: 400px;" name="body" id="textbody">Data fetched from database goes here ...</textarea>
        <br/>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my laravel controller :

```
public function upload()
{
    if(Input::hasFile('photo'))
    {
        $allowedext = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"];
        $photo = Input::file('photo');
        $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/templates';
        $filename = str_random(12);
        $extension = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if(in_array($extension, $allowedext))
        {
            Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $filename . '.' . $extension);
        } else
        {
            return json_encode('File format not supported');
        }

        return json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'url' => '/uploads/templates/' . $filename . '.' . $extension]);
    } else
    {
        return json_encode(['status' => 'failure']);
    }
}
```

**EDIT** tinyMCE calling script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor"
    ],

    toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
    toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor image media code | inserttime preview | forecolor backcolor",
    toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap emoticons | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft",

    menubar: false,
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',

    style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ],

    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});</script>
```

Most probably the problem is between line 18-23 in javascript

Comment: put your `tinymce` calling script(javascript) for `textbody` here

Comment: @SimhachalamGulla added

Comment: I rollbacked your last modification: you can't transform a question into working code. Instead you need to post (or accept) an answer. Or what you can do is simplify your question to make it an MCVE (minimal code needed to reproduce the issue)

Comment: I have already accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the image element to the tinymce source element instead of the editor. Try to use this on ajax success:

```
success: function (data) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    if(parsed.status === 'success')
    {
        // gets the editor body
        var editor = tinymce.get('textbody');

        // create the image tag as a string
        var html = '<img src="' +parsed.url +'">';

        // insert the image at the caret position of the editor
        editor.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html);
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked thank you so much ! can I also tell ajax place this image where the cursor in the editor is ?

Comment: I should place edited line of code instead of $(editor_body).prepend(html) ?

Comment: Thank you so much you are a life saviour, can you also explain what actually is happening in the code

Comment: Hmm, it is more or less already in the comments. tinymce.get('editor_id'); is the tinymce way of getting an editor by its id (the id matches the id of the editor source element - in your case 'textbody'. Using the execCommand insertHTML you can enter a predefined string at the actual caret position or dom range (you would overwrite selected text). See this info page for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `setup` block for init script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor"
    ],

    toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
    toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor image media code | inserttime preview | forecolor backcolor",
    toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap emoticons | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft",

    menubar: false,
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',

    style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ],

    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ],
    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.on('change', function(e) {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Which version of tinymce you are using?

Comment: in my /tinymce/tinymce.min.js file I have //4.3.0. so I believe that its version 4.3.0

Comment: I don't see any changes in my code and the fiddle, can you point out what did you change?

Comment: `setup` code <br/>
templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ],
    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.on('change', function(e) {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        });
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96011/discussion-between-simhachalam-gulla-and-khan-shahrukh).

Comment: thank you! this little part saved my life ```setup: function(ed) {
        ed.on('change', function(e) {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        });
    }```